# Overwrite existing score if new score is higher

Tags: php, mysql, sql

On submitting (ID, username, score), I only want the database to update if the score is higher than the usernames previous score.

So far I have

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO $db_name.$db_table (ID, name, score)
                               VALUES ((ID, name , score) IF $ID=ID & $name=name & '$score'>score);");
```

Full code is

```
if(isset($_GET['ID']) & isset($_GET['name']) & isset($_GET['score'])){

$con = mysqli_connect($host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);


$ID = strip_tags(mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['ID']));
$name = strip_tags(mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['name']));
$score = strip_tags(mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['score']));

$sql = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO $db_name.$db_table (ID, name, score)
                           VALUES ((ID, name , score) IF $ID=ID & $name=name & '$score'>score);");


if($sql){

    //The query returned true - now do whatever you like here.
    echo 'Your score was saved. Congrats!';
    
}else{
 
    //The query returned false - you might want to put some sort of error reporting here. Even logging the error to a text file is fine.
   echo("<br>Error description: " . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_close($con);//Close off the MySQLI connection to save resources.
```

Comment: **Warning**: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized prepared statements instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](https://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: would you want to record multiple row of scores for the same user, or just one per user, and replace the lower value to new, higher one?

Comment: you didn't actually explain what the problem is. You said what you want, but didn't relate that to the current code at all. What is going wrong exactly?

Comment: @ariefbayu yes, currently the scoreboard shows top 20 scores. But top 5 are all by the same user. So i just one the top user to have their score overwritten by a new higher one if achieved.

Comment: @ADyson error code i am getting is
"Error description: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF Jaydog182=ID & jaydob=name & '913'>score)' at line 2"

Comment: Ah ok. SQL doesn't have `IF` statements. Well, it does, but you can't put them within another query. Gordon's answer below shows you a sensible way to approach this requirement. In future, when you're asking here, please include any error messages you're getting. It makes your question a lot clearer. See [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info. Also please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) (I can see by the lack of badge in your profile that you haven't...it should have been recommended to you when you signed up to the site).

Comment: @ADyson Got Gordons answer to work. I'll have a look through the tour as suggested.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to want `on duplicate key update`.  You want one row per `name`, so you need a unique index or cosntraint on name:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unq_table_name ON $db_name.$db_table(name);
```

Then you can use:

```
INSERT INTO $db_name.$db_table (ID, name, score)
    VALUES (ID, name, score)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE score = GREATEST(score, VALUES(score));
```

The use of `$db_name.$db_table` is highly problematic.  It suggests that a single entity (whatever should be in the table) is spread through multiple tables.  That is really bad *data modeling*.

In addition, it potentially opens the code to SQL injection and hard to debug syntax errors.  I would recommend that you re-think your database design so you have scores in only one table, perhaps called `user_scores` or something more intelligible than `$db_name.$db_table`.